# Can My Company Block Websites Though An SSH Tunnel?

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I am trying to tunnel through a firewall on a client site so that I can reach my company email.

I have created an SSH Tunnel using putty by adding a Dynamic port (6666) in the Tunnels then logging into my company server.

I have set the Firefox connection settings to use SOCKS and 127.0.0.1 6666.

I can seemingly browse all http web pages with this setup.

I can also reach some https sites. e.g.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-tell-if-my-connection-is-secure https://encrypted.google.com/

If I do the following from the server I get `Connected to www.google.com.`

```
telnet www.google.com 443
```

The problem is that if I try to access my company Outlook Web Access on https it never loads.
Is it possible that it is being blocked/filtered somehow?

If not, what can I do to diagnose this problem?

Comment: What filtering does your company have in place for access to their Outlook Web Access?  What do you get if from the server you do `telnet outlook.web.access.system 443`?

Comment: Try the following: In Firefox open `about:config`, find the setting called `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` set it to `true`. (The default for this setting is `false`, but in most cases `true` works better.)

Comment: When I set `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` to `true` (or tick the box in the network settings) I can't even browse http sites anymore. I can't telnet to owa from the server (although I can telnet to another company https site that I am struggling to access) I am checking to see if there is a better server to use.